# Change script to act for battery level instead of temperature

Tags: scripting, battery

I have a script that can put the computer to sleep at a certain CPU temperature;

```
#!/bin/bash

 while true; do
        val=$(sensors | awk '/temp1/ {print $2}')
        max=$(echo "+82.0")
        if [[ "$val" > "$max" ]]
                then
                        systemctl suspend -i

        fi
    sleep 5
        clear
        sensors
 done
 exit 0
```

Can it be adjusted/edited to put te computer to sleep at a certain battery level?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your system you should be able to get the battery percentage level in bash from

```
 level=$(</sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity)
 echo $level
```

Check the directories and files under `/sys/class/power_supply/` for the name of your device and other information.  You may also have the `upower` command for more descriptive data:

```
$ upower -d
...
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               YYYYY
  model:                XXXX
  power supply:         yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    energy:              23.436 Wh
    energy-full:         26.622 Wh
    energy-rate:         5.5728 W
    voltage:             11.97 V
    time to empty:       4.2 hours
    percentage:          88%
```